# WIX Setup, Change install folder selected from another program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm working on a project. It includes several parts. One part is a program where user selects all kinds of options. One option (OptA) is where program A should be installed to.

The installer of Program A is built by WIX Setup. It installs to C:\Program Files (x86) without pop the destination selection dialog.

Is there a way to install Program A to folder OptA? If yes, how? My guess is that we will have to have a variable to get the value of OptA?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your program (where user selects all kinds of options) then launch the installer for Program A? If so, then you can specify values for public properties defined in the MSI using the following syntax:

```
msiexec /i programA.msi INSTALLFOLDER="some\path\where\to\install"
```

For this to work the MSI for Program A must expose a public property that maps to the directory where the program will be installed (that's **INSTALLFOLDER** in the example above)

If you own the Wix installer project, then you can just edit it to make sure you are exposing the install directory. If not, you'll want to use a tool such as [Orca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Wix dark](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html) to inspect the MSI and identify if the install directory property is available and what it is called. It might be called INSTALLDIR or INSTALLFOLDER or INSTALLDIRECTORY or something along those lines.